# Closed epicycloids

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider a system of $n+1$ celestial bodies - e.g. a sun, a planet, a moon, a satellite of the moon and a satellite of the satellite - which run around each other on circles in the same plane but with possibly different periods. In this snapshot all bodies are in [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy)):

[image]

The blue planet draws a circle, the red moon draws an [epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid), the satellites  draw ever higher epicyloids.

With the sun in the origin, the curve drawn by the last satellite can be given by a function $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ by

$f_1(t) = r_1 e^{i(\omega_1 t + \varphi_1)}$ (the planet draws a circle)

$f_2(t) = f_1(t) + r_2 e^{i(\omega_2 t + \varphi_2)}$ (the moon draws an epicycloid)

$\dots$

$f_n(t) = f_{n-1}(t) + r_n e^{i(\omega_n t + \varphi_n)}$

or simply

$$\boxed{f_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k e^{i\omega_k t}}$$

with $c_k = r_k e^{i\varphi_k}$.

In the picture above (all bodies are in conjunction) we have $\varphi_k = 0$, so $c_k = r_k \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is another case with $c_k \not\in \mathbb{R}$:

[image]

It's an astonishing fact that when choosing the right number of satellites, radii, periods and phases:

> The curve drawn by the last satellite can approximate any sufficiently
>   smooth closed curve arbitrarily well.

There is a beautiful demonstration [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171756):

[image]

Even though this fact is astonishing (i.e. not obvious), it is elementary. What **is** obvious is another elementary fact:

> When all periods are pairwise rationally related, i.e. $\frac{\omega_i}{ \omega_j}$ is a rational number, then the curves of all bodies are
>   closed,  especially the curve of the last satellite.

My question concerns the other direction:

> Is it true (and how to prove) that when the curve of the last satellite is closed then all periods are pairwise rationally related?

Comment: Nice question! This reduces to proving that (if it is true) if $T_1(x),T_2(x)$ are periodic with respective periods $t_1,t_2$, then $T_1(x)+T_2(x)$ is periodic if and **only if** $t_1$ and $t_2$ are rationally related. Honestly, I'm skeptical... it seems like maybe one could come up with a crafty counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WOLOG, we  will assume all $c_j \ne 0$ and $\omega_j$ are distinct.

By closed, I will assume you mean $f_n(t)$ is periodic for some period $T$.
If that is the case, then all its derivatives are periodic. For $k = 1, \ldots, n$, we have
$$f^{(k-1)}_n(T) = f^{(k-1)}_n(0)
\quad\iff\quad \sum_{j=1}^n \omega_j^{k-1} c_j(e^{i\omega_j T}-1) = 0
$$
Let

- $A = (a_{kj})$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{kj} = \omega_j^{k-1}$.
- $u = (u_j)$ be the column vector with entries $c_j(e^{i\omega_jT} - 1)$.

Above equation is equivalent to $A u = 0$. For distinct $\omega_j$, $A$ has the form of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and is known to be invertible. This leads to $u = 0$. This means for any $j = 1,\ldots, n$,

$$c_j (e^{i\omega_j T} - 1 ) = 0 \quad\implies\quad e^{i\omega_j T} = 1
\quad\implies\quad \omega_j = \frac{2\pi m_j}{T}\quad\text{ for some } m_j \in \mathbb{Z}$$

From this, we can deduce $T$ is "a" period of $f_\ell(t)$ for $\ell = 1,\ldots,n$.