# Coupling mathematics and physics by pendulums

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Consider a [multi-pendulum system](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipendel) , i.e. a set of points $P_0, P_1,\dots, P_n$ with masses $m_k$, connected by massless rods of length $l_k$, which thus may rotate around each other. $P_0$ is fixed.

[image]

The state of the system at time $t$ can generally be given by $n$ complex numbers

$z_1(t) = l_1e^{i\Phi_1(t)}$

$z_2(t) = z_1(t) + l_2e^{i\Phi_2(t)}$

$z_3(t) = z_2(t) + l_3e^{i\Phi_3(t)}$

$\dots$

$z_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n l_ke^{i\Phi_k(t)} $

---

In the case of **massless points**, i.e. $m_k = 0$ for all $k$, there is an explicit solution:

$z_1(t) = l_1e^{i(\omega_1 t + \varphi_1)}$

$z_2(t) = z_1(t) + l_2e^{i(\omega_2 t + \varphi_2)}$

$\dots$

$z_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n l_ke^{i(\omega_k t + \varphi_k)} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_ke^{i\omega_k t}$

with $c_k = l_ke^{i\varphi_k}$ and $\omega_k$, $\varphi_k$ reflecting the initial conditions.

Findings:

- The system's trajectory in phase space is periodic iff $z_k(t)$ is periodic for all $k$.
- $z_n(t)$ is periodic iff $\omega_k/\omega_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $k$. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2968543/1792))
- $\rightarrow z_k(t)$ is periodic for all $k$ iff $z_n(t)$ is periodic.
- Any reasonable closed curve can be approximated by such a periodic system. (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171756))

---

When the **points are subject to gravity***, then

- even the most simple system with $n=2$ ([double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum)), $l_1 = l_2$, $m_1 = m_2$ has no explicit solution and in general no closed trajectories in phase space
- the system behaves chaotically and ergodically
- [there **may** be initial conditions that give rise to closed trajectories](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363497/229) both in position and phase space – but it's not clear (to me) how to find them.

<sup>* as opposed to [gravitation](https://www.quora.com/How-do-gravity-and-gravitation-differ)</sup>

---

One missing piece between these two cases – massless points and points which are subject to gravity – is the case of **points with inert masses**.

In the massless case (the purely "mathematical" one), any point can be arbitraryly fast, but in the non-massless case (the most simple "physical" one) the total kinetic energy of all points must be conserved – which makes the difference.

My question is:

> What are the relevant findings for **multi-pendulum systems of inert points**?
>
> - May there be explicit formulas for the trajectories as in the case of massless points?
> - Is there an easy criterion for periodicity in phase space?

Moreover: When [complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis) is the framework for "massless pendulums" and the [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is the prototype for "gravitational pendulums", what's the mathematical framework or prototype for "inert pendulums"?

**Examples:**

[image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image]

---

The final missing piece would be **points with pairwise gravitational forces**, i.e. the true [n-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem). But that's another story.